# VisualStudio 2017 preview 2 doesn't load Unit tests with .NET Core 2.0.0-preview2-006391

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, .net-core

In the last two days I've had some trouble with Unit Testing in VS 2017 preview 2. Yesterday I've installed the last version of .NET core, I've updated every package inside my project and, since then, I haven't been able to see not a single test in VisualStudio's Test Explorer . If run the command "dotnet test" in the PowerShell everything works and I receive the information of test's execution. What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using the release version of VS 2017?

Comment: Of course! But .NET Core 2.0 preview works only with the preview version of VS

Comment: Ahh, I'm sorry, I misunderstood.  I thought you were talking about still using one of the (very old) release candidates from before it actually launched.

Comment: Easy :) Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've opened an issue on the official VisualStudio github, 'cause it seems that this version of Vs is quite instable.

https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/858

;)